# Can I improve this jQuery code repetition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to learn best practices with jQuery and how to avoid code reptition and use elegant code.

I've written:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Change the category name with the filter
  $(function() {

    // Featured
    $('.featured').click(function() {
      $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html('Featured').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    // Web
    $('.web').click(function() {
      $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html('Web').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    // Brand
    $('.brand').click(function() {
      $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html('Brand').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    // Print
    $('.print').click(function() {
      $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html('Print').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    // All
    $('.all').click(function() {
      $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html('All').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li><a class="featured" href="#" data-filter=".feature-this">Featured</a></li>
    <li><a class="web" href="#" data-filter=".category-web">Web</a></li>
    <li><a class="brand" href="#" data-filter=".category-brand">Brand</a></li>
    <li><a class="print" href="#" data-filter=".category-print">Print</a></li>
    <li><a class="all" href="#" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="categoryTitle"> <h1>Featured</h1> </div>
```

Is this as elegant as it can be, or am I missing how to stop diving into the DOM as much?

**Note** I am using Isotope, a jQuery plugin.

**Edit** None of the answers are currently changing categoryTitle, but I did ommit that it has a default value of Featured.

Comment: Yeah, part of the cleanup needs to be in your HTMl. Post that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/welcome/25063/edit)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#filters').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $(".categoryTitle").find("h1").hide().html($(this).text()).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think this won't work, as it doesn't seem that the `h1` is a child element of `$(this)`.

Comment: It's not updating categoryTitle

Comment: see the demo link in my answer

Comment: I can't for the life of me work out why this isn't working for me.

Comment: look at the console if you find a error also can you show us the page (if its live) where you are getting a error

Comment: It's localhost, but i'm not getting any errors at all. I'll try clearing my cache..

Comment: can you create a demo on http://jsbin.com/  by simply copy paste you markup and js

Comment: Nope. No idea.  How strange indeed.

Comment: I dont think I can create a jsbin, it's a wordpress template

Comment: and the code you have previously written was working ? i mean the code in your question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16954/discussion-between-champ-and-smacfadyen)

Comment: I've accepted this for other people and thank you for your time Champ.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#filters').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html($(this).text()).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't get the text from #filters a

Comment: Oh really? Strange. I've got it [working in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7Ncm/). Note that I added `e.preventDefault()` - you can leave that out if you like, but it stops the default append of the `#` character (fragment) to the URL.

Comment: The categoryTitle h1 has a default value of Featured

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - the default value will be whatever is in the HTML. I left it blank in my example. Are you saying my example isn't working for you? What version of jQuery are you using, and are there any console errors? You may need to change `.on()` to `.bind()` if you're using an older version.

Comment: I'm baffled too - I'm using jQuery 1.8.0 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
function change(id){
$('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html(id).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
  $('#filters a').click(function() {
        $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html($(this).text()).fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul#filters li a').click(function(){
           $('.categoryTitle h1').hide().html($(this).text()).fadeIn('slow')

   });
});
```